# How to have a y-scrollbar with a v-row as a child element

Tags: html, css, vue.js, overflow

How can I have a scrollbar appear from the parent v-row (very important) with the child v-row overflowing with content so I can add another v-row inside the v-col and for it to still be inside the scroll element

```
<v-row> 
  <v-col>
    <v-row>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam elementum tellus nec urna dignissim ullamcorper. Sed vitae erat ultricies, elementum ligula sit amet, maximus leo. Nunc nec arcu ante. Proin commodo est orci, ornare laoreet ipsum mollis in. Donec egestas sollicitudin ultrices. Nam quis tempus nunc, vulputate luctus mi.</p>    
    </v-row>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what `v-row` and `v-col` are but I assume they're from a component framework like Vue-Bootstrap. Generally, what you want to do is to add `style="overflow-y: scroll; max-width: 100%;"` to the top `v-row` where max-width is the widest you want the window to stretch.

Comment: I forgot to mention I want an overflow-x but the content in the second v-row just goes back to the line when it reaches the max width